# Remove trailing line on the last item of Timeline boostrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to remove the trailing horizontal line after the last item of the timeline below. I have tried creating a class `timeline-item-last` which doesn't work. I believe there's a more elegant way to go with this. Any ideas?

```
.timeline-item-last {

  border-right: 0px solid #ffffff !important;

}
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/usershakalaka/sjduc836/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `.timeline-horizontal:before` pseudo class as it's no longer needed, and replace the `.timeline:before` selector with:

```
.timeline:before {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    content: "";
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    left: 40px;
    width: 65%;
    margin-left: -1.5px;
}
```

It should fix the issue.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sjduc836/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/sjduc836/6/

```js
getPos = function(){
  $('.horizontalLine').css({
    left: $('.timeline-badge').first().position().left,
    width: $('.timeline-item-last').position().left
  });
}

getPos();

$(window).resize(function(){
 getPos();
});
```

```css
/* Timeline */
.timeline,
.timeline-horizontal {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.horizontalLine {
  bottom: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin-left: -1.5px;
  height: 3px;
}
.timeline .timeline-item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.timeline .timeline-item:before,
.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  clear: both;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge {
  color: #fff;
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  line-height: 52px;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background-color: #7c7c7c;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge i,
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge .fa,
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge .glyphicon {
  top: 2px;
  left: 0px;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.primary {
  background-color: #1f9eba;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.info {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.success {
  background-color: #59ba1f;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.warning {
  background-color: #d1bd10;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.danger {
  background-color: #ba1f1f;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel {
  position: relative;
  width: 46%;
  float: left;
  right: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
}
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  right: -16px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 16px solid transparent;
  border-left: 16px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-right: 0 solid #c0c0c0;
  border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
}
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: inherit;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-body > p,
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-body > ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-body > p + p {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.timeline .timeline-item:last-child:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}
.timeline .timeline-item:nth-child(even) .timeline-panel {
  float: right;
  left: 16px;
}
.timeline .timeline-item:nth-child(even) .timeline-panel:before {
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 14px;
  left: -14px;
  right: auto;
}
.timeline-horizontal {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.timeline-horizontal:before {
  height: 3px;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 26px;
  left: 26px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.timeline-horizontal .timeline-item {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 280px;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 120px;
  float: none !important;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.timeline-horizontal .timeline-item .timeline-panel {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 64px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: none !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.timeline-horizontal .timeline-item .timeline-panel:before {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -16px;
  left: 28px !important;
  right: auto;
  border-right: 16px solid transparent !important;
  border-top: 16px solid #c0c0c0 !important;
  border-bottom: 0 solid #c0c0c0 !important;
  border-left: 16px solid transparent !important;
}
.timeline-item-last {

  border-right: 0px solid #ffffff !important;

}
.timeline-horizontal .timeline-item:before,
.timeline-horizontal .timeline-item:after {
  display: none;
}
.timeline-horizontal .timeline-item .timeline-badge {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 43px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="page-header">
       <h1>Horizontal timeline</h1>
     </div>
     <div style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">
          
     <ul class="timeline timeline-horizontal">
      <li class="timeline-item">
       <div class="timeline-badge primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i></div>
      </li>
      <li class="timeline-item">
       <div class="timeline-badge primary"><i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
       <div class="timeline-panel">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
         <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum cacilds 2</h4>         
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-body">
         <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros gostis.</p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </li>   
      <li class="timeline-item timeline-item-last">
       <div class="timeline-badge success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i></div>      
      </li>
     </ul>
          <div class="horizontalLine"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 
  </div>
```

Instead of **pseudo element**, I created a **div** & calculated the **width** based on the **first** & **last** **li** element.